# CSS Property being overridden in IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So I've been working on a website, where I have the following CSS for the navigation bar:

```
.boxshadow div#top_nav li+li::before, .no-boxshadow div#top_nav li+li::before{
    content:url('media/images/link.gif');
}
```

It's supposed to create link separators for the list items in the nav bar, by inserting a certain image before all links except the first one. The `.boxshadow` and `.no-boxshadow` classes are due to Modernizr.

The problem is, it's being overridden in IE. It appears to be crossed out when I open the Developer Tools, so I know it's being overridden, but I don't know why. In Chrome and Firefox, the property works, but only in IE I'm having this problem.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I'd be happy to post more CSS if necessary. All help is appreciated.

Here's a link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KJYe2/

Edit 2: Sorry guys, but it seems to work in IE through jsFiddle. However, it doesn't show locally on my computer, and I'm not sure why...I tried posting more relevant CSS that's used before the navigation bar, to see if any of those rules were causing the override, but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Which IE? They're very different animals.

Comment: It's important to indicate WHICH VERSION of IE you are talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry about that; the problem is in IE9, and it also replicates when I emulate IE8 and IE7 in the developer tools. I'll post a fiddle in a bit, as I'm away from my computer right now. Thanks a lot to all of you.

Comment: You don't need the `boxshadow`/`no-boxshadow` bit if you're setting it to the same style either way; just drop it down to `#top_nav li+li::before` and you'll have pretty much the same selector as before, but much less typing.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had that before. I only put that there to see if the lack of classes was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm such an idiot. It turns out it works fine live, but locally it just doesn't render. I'm not sure why it does that as opposed to Chrome and Firefox (it renders fine locally on those browsers), but for IE, it only works live. Strangely enough though, it's still crossed out in the IE9 dev tools both offline and online. I apologize for the inconvenience I may have caused, and appreciate all who helped in the matter. Thanks!